# Converting all <? to <?php

Tags: phpstorm

I have a huge PHP project consisting of many PHP files, most of them opening with `<?`. Now I'm trying to run this in PHP5.4, so I need to convert all of these to `<?php`.

Hence my question;

**How do I convert all opening tags from `<?` to `<?php` ?**

I use JetBrains PhpStorm 7.0.

Comment: Search and replace all `<?` with `<?php`? It's unlikely that you have `<?` in your code other than the PHP tag. Not sure about PhpStorm, but in Eclipse you can go one by one, and then replace in a bunch.

Comment: @elclanrs: wrong. Search and replace all `<? ` or `<?\n`, not `<?` or you will end with bunch of `<?<?php`

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: Not sure why make the distinction, in Vim I'd just do `s/<?/<?php/g` and that works. Then I'd probably do `s/<?php=/<?=/` if I replaced short echo tags.

Comment: You can search in PhpStorm with this regular expression: `^\<\?$`

Comment: In PHPStorm, right click on the project source root directory. Click ***Replace In path***. Select only ***Regular Expression***, Set Context to: ***except comments and string literals*** set File masks to `*.php` (or your project's PHP extension(s)) Text to Find: `<\?=\s?` Replace:  `<?php echo `. Click Find. After it finds all, click ***Review***, Ignore those you wish to, and click ***Replace All*** Repeat for Find: `<\?(\s|\n)` Replace: `<?php$1`.

Comment: The answer above from fyrye will doe the trick. Do a search and replace for `<\?(\s|\n)` (expression) and replace with `<?php `. Notice the `space`. This replace all `<?` and `<?\n` tags, but doesn't change the `<?php` tags.

Comment: On VSCode replace `<\?$`  to <?php

Comment: Voting Reopen as the answer to which points this "duplicate" does not address OP's problem exactly. OP is asking how to fix the tags *in PhpStorm*, not in general

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem could be solved according to comments. However, I chose to update php.ini to accept short open tags instead.

Answer (score 2):

Try this if on Linux, you have access to a nice sed

```
find . -name '*.php' -exec sed -i '1s/<?$/<\?php/' {} \; -exec echo Fixing {} \;
```

Comment: 403 files later...